# How do I create a proper metaclass for my task?

Tags: python, weak-references, metaclass

I have task creating an iterable class which on **iter** returns an iterator on the list of instance already created from this class, for example:

```
x = SomeClass()
y = SomeClass()
for obj in SomeClass:
    print obj
>><__main__.SomeClass object at .......> and etc
```

I made it through the metaclass and globals(). It looks terrible, but it works. And I want to find a more elegant and pythonic way; at first I want to make this through a weakref, but I don't understand how I can get some variables from the working class from my metaclass and when I try to store refs on objects in my meta class it is creating a ref to my class, and so this is my implementation:

```
class ObjectsInMemory(object):

    class __metaclass__(type):
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.name = args[0]
       def __iter__(self):
            glob = globals().copy()
            cls_inst = []
            for _, v in glob.iteritems():
                try:
                    if self.name in v.__repr__():
                        cls_inst.append(v)
                except TypeError:
                    pass
            yield cls_inst
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep track of instances of some class, I'd recommend using a weakly-referencing container for this, like `weakref.WeakSet`. A code sketch of such a container class:

```py
import weakref

class InstanceTracker(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.instances = {}
    def new(self, cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        self.instances.setdefault(cls, weakref.WeakSet()).add(instance)
        return instance
    def iter_instances(cls):
        return iter(self.instances[cls])
```

You can now create new instances of `SomeClass` with `tracker.new(SomeClass)` for an `InstanceTracker` instance `tracker`.

This way, you don't have to rely on global state, your functions don't have strange side effects, and you don't need to modify a class to track its instances.

Comment: +1 for InstanceTracker object idea -- even though it takes more management to keep it around, it's a lot cleaner than metaclasses or globals.

Comment: It only took two extra lines to write the metaclass, and it is simple once you understand how metaclasses work.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower: I do know how to do this with metaclasses.  I dislike the solution anyway, due to its hidden global state and the counter-intuitive class iteration behaviour.  It might be an interesting exercise to implement this, but in practice, I'd prefer the simpler and more explicit solution.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I did not understand metaclasses before this summer but forced myself to learn more about them and was surprised at the power they provide.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I think you have the wrong approach for the functionality you're seeking.

First off, globals are bad -- avoid them if you at all can. Second you really don't need to make a metaclass to create a global iterable. Instead try the following:

```
class SomeClass():
    ALL_INSTANCES = set()
    def __init__(self):
        self.ALL_INSTANCES.add(self)

for obj in SomeClass.ALL_INSTANCES:
    print obj
```

This gives you the same iterable functionality without the horrible mess of metaclasses. Also it hides the global definition within the SomeClass scope, so you have less of the worries of globals (though not all, as it still keeps global state).

Note that you can't easily remove objects in the ALL_INSTANCES because `__del__` won't get called automatically as you inherently have a reference to the object as long as the Class type exists. A manually `del` call with `__del__` defined would remove the object from the global set (once the last reference is gone -- unless there is a circular reference), but this relies on the user remembering to do so. That being said with this structure you should assume all objects live indefinitely.

Or you could use weak references in a WeakSet and make sure `__del__` actually removes from the working set. But it's still not guaranteed to be called because of cyclic references (at the very least), so 'dead' objects may still live in the live instances global.

Comment: I'd Suggest to use a `WeakSet` instead of a `set` to prevent instances from staying around forever.  Also note that while `ALL_INSTANCES` isn't in the global *scope*, it's still global *state*.  This means things like unit testing will still be messy.   Given the simplicity of the solution, this might get the job done in certain situations anyway, +1.

Comment: Also note that `del` does not automatically call `__del__()` even when defined.  It  only deletes a single reference.  If there are further references, as would be the case ith the reference in `ALL_INSTANCES`, the object will stay alive.

Comment: @SvenMarnach WeakSet would probably be better overall, it was unclear to me if he wanted objects to persist or not. I'll update the part where I mentioned weak references. Though I think I would actually use your implementation if I wanted object tracking in my own code because of the global state issues you pointed out.

Comment: Would a metaclass not be a more general solution that could be more easily applied to any other class without having to write as much code each time?

Comment: @NoctisSkytower If you were repeating the structure a lot, yes a metaclass would be more general and a better fit. But if it's only used a couple times then the simpler, less error prone solution is best imo. My answer only shows the simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is an interesting metaclass requirement but was rather simple to write in Python 3 (took a few minutes).

---

**Code:**

```
import weakref

class InstanceIter(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, class_dict):
        new_class = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, class_dict)
        new_class.__instances = weakref.WeakSet()
        return new_class

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__instances.add(instance)
        return instance

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__instances)

class SomeClass(metaclass=InstanceIter):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{!s}({!r})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.name)
```

Testing to make sure the code worked turned out to be easy as well. Weak references help with memory.

---

**Test:**

```
>>> a, b, c, d, e = (SomeClass(name) for name in 'vwxyz')
>>> tuple(SomeClass)
(SomeClass('v'), SomeClass('y'), SomeClass('x'), SomeClass('z'), SomeClass('w'))
>>>
```

Comment: Note that the OP is using Python 2.x, not 3.x.